# login window on another view controller iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, oauth, fbconnect

In Facebook API in FBDialoge.m file ,

I want that login window to open on another VC,
so in FBDialoge.m file ,

I am changing this code ..

```
UIWindow* window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
[window addSubview:self];
[window addSubview:_modalBackgroundView];
```

to

```
 SettingsPopover *svp = [[SettingsPopover alloc] init];
[svp.view addSubview:self];
[svp.view addSubview:_modalBackgroundView];
```

but that login window is not coming on SettingsPopover , can anyone tell me what should I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here instance of SettingsPopover *svp is new one which will add subviews but will not take effect until this new instance is used.  Where ever u  added SettingsPopover  in viewcontroller that the reference i m talking about.

I mean u need original reference of SettingsPopover to take effect by adding subview.

Comment: In my app , one of the popovers is SettingsPopover in which Facebook login is there . I just press that button and whole this things are getting called (FBConnect one) and it is showing big login screen on the app . I want that screen on that popover only .

Comment: so .. as original reference what actually you want me to do here?